# Start recording audio from lock screen

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, tasker, audio-recording, android-13

Is there a way to add the Recorder app to the lock screen? I would like to be able to be able to quickly start recording audio. Kind of like how the camera app can be opened from the lock screen. Is it possible to record as soon as the app starts without hitting the record button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the Android development guide

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder

> Note: On devices running Android 9 (API level 28) or higher, apps
> running in the background cannot access the microphone. Therefore,
> your app should record audio only when it's in the foreground or when
> you include an instance of MediaRecorder in a foreground service.